# Drake matrix indexing issue

Tags: drake

This code errors in Drake:

```
forces_matrix = np.zeros((T - 1, O, O, D))
tril_indices = np.tril_indices(O, m=O, k=-1)
forces_matrix[:, tril_indices[0], tril_indices[1]] = f_oo
```

But it works in PyTorch / Numpy.

The LHS and RHS are both 9, 1, 1 shape numpy tensors.

Is this type of operation not supported in Drake?

EDIT: No more syntax error if the initial forces_matrix is OBJECT type. However, I am not sure if the computation graph is being built correctly connecting f_oo and forces_matrix. Is this type of operation supported?

Comment: I think we would need more context to help. There is no Drake code in that sample?